# Checkmarx Issue: Insecure Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkmarx, self-host-webapi

In the below code I got a Checkmarx issue of *Insecure Cookie*/

In the `Startup` class, I'm using self-host API.

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        string Mutex_id = "Recorder";
        using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, Mutex_id))
        {
            if (!mutex.WaitOne(0,false))
            {
                return;
            }
            string baseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("BaseAddress");

            // Start OWIN host 
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
            {
                Application.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
    // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    }
}
```

Here is the Checkmarx report:

[image]

Comment: Please copy the error message from the screenshot to the question.

Comment: @Pragyanand, is your  self hosted api using cookie authentication or is using any cookie at all?

Comment: @securecodeninja No, I'm not ussing any cookie at all .

Comment: @Pragyanand then this would be a false positive then